# react-native Android - Images blank after ./gradlew installRelease

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to get a release bundle prepared. My app looks as it should on Genymotion but when I bundle the app(`./gradlew assembleRelease`) then run it on Genymotion(`./gradlew installRelease`) my images do not appear. I have been scouring the docs and cannot seem to find any information on this.

I have seen this particular problem in closed issues, but, in each case, I am either already implementing the solution or the proposed solution is deprecated/doesn't work.

RN 0.27.2

Comment: Just a guess, but what are the sizes (both pixel and kb) of your images?

We ran into similar problems of application crashing and not displaying images when we had large images. They had to be downscaled for Android.